# What is your hourly SharePoint rates in us dollar

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am fairly new to development but I like to day dream about future, Anyone who would like to share there hourly rate either for development or adminstration in US dollars would be thankful. May include your location of country too.

Answer (score 1):

so this is very much open ended question.

SharePoint hourly rate /salary depends upon the level of your expertise,

- Number of year of experince in sharepoint
- developer or Admin
- Architect
- If you are in USA then depend upon your immigration status.
- the state the project is (some states having higher cost of living so billing rate higher i.e California.)

Now a days, from entry level to expert. Billing rate start from $40 to 150$ per hour.
You can check the trend on the different job portals, they mentioned rates in many job posting. i.e Dice, careerbuilder or monster

Answer (score 0):

I am getting $20 per hour in Russia, 2 year experience in sharepoint development.